# where to find java based projects?

Tags: projects

I have 5 years of experience in JAVA. I want to improve my coding skills by working on projects.

Can you tell me any place on WEB which can fetch me projects?

Note: I am not looking for freelancing in particular. I am talking about the programs conducting by various companies or websites for developing projects.

I can work on freelancing as well. Please suggest the right place to work and improve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [GitHub](https://github.com/)? There are thousands of projects in many languages including Java.

I recommend signing up in order to make the most of it. That way you can follow projects you are interested in and connect with other developers. I believe you need to be a member to be able to contribute to many projects.

Comment: Hi @Ciara, I have seen the website. It has lot of projects. Just a piece of advice, does signing up for free help?

Comment: Hi @PrakrutiPathik, yes signing up is a good idea, see my edit. You don't have to be a member to download code but it helps if you want to get involved in a particular project.